# Mac "open" command opens directories with Skim, not Finder

Tags: terminal, finder, skim

The `open` command on my mac breaks when I install [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/), a PDF viewer.

When I try to use `open` to browse a directory with Skim installed, `open` launches the Skim app, and I am presented with the following message:

[image]

How do I make `open` behave properly, and open directories using Finder, like it should?

It reverts back to the expected behavior when I move Skim to Trash.

Comment: If you uninstall Skim, does "open /" works?

Comment: Yes. (P.S. this is not a full uninstall, just a move to trash)